# puppet auth.conf allow hostname isn't working

Tags: puppet

I've got puppet master set up with foreman on (say) node vdc1 which has ip 10.200.201.191. I've got a puppet agent running on vdc2 with ip 10.200.201.192. vdc2 can ping vdc1 using both "vdc1" and its ip.

In the auth.conf of vdc2, I have the following:

```
# added to enable puppetrun
path /run
method save
auth any
allow vdc1

# this one is not stricly necessary, but it has the merit
# to show the default policy which is deny everything else
path /
auth any
```

Now if I do a puppet kick from vdc1 to vdc2 with:

```
puppet kick vdc2
```

the request fails. However, if I change the first allow in auth.conf to:

```
allow 10.200.201.191
```

or

```
allow *
```

it runs fine. Is there something I need to do so that I can use a DNS entry for the puppet master instead of specifying an ip?

EDIT:
Here's the error I get:

```
Error: Host vdc2 failed: Error 403 on SERVER: Forbidden request: 10.200.201.191(10.200.201.191) access to /run/vdcapp2 [save] at :2
```

Comment: Should that not be `allow vdc2` not `vdc1`? But I suppose that won't work either. - Have you tried querying the `puppet agent --configprint certname` value on the agent node and using the result in your `allow` rule? Besides IP addresses, `auth.conf` can contain rules that are based on the agent certificate, iirc.

Comment: I'll give that a go. vdc1 is the puppet master, hence I expected the allow to have that. Using the ip of the puppet master works.

Comment: Just confirmed. printing certname gives the fqn of the agent node (not the master). Using vdc2 or the fqn of vdc2 doesn't work either.

Comment: OK, I was confused because you are mucking around `auth.conf` on an agent machine, which I never tried.
So have you tried the `fqdn` of the vdc1 machine? Ah, but then `10.200.201.191(10.200.201.191)` seems to indicate that nothing is resolved at all. Try a hosts entry of `10.200.201.191 vdc1 vdc1.your.domain` on vdc2.

Comment: I'll try that. But...if I enter vdc1 in auth.conf, it says Forbidden request 10.200.201.191 (which is the ip of vdc1). That would suggest it's resolving correctly? If it weren't, how would it know what the ip is?

Comment: The IP is not from `auth.conf` - it's from the original request that is being denied.